# Which one should I choose for log management, systemd-journald or rsyslog?

Tags: rsyslog, systemd-journald

We have both **systemd-journald** and **rsyslog** running on our linux box, and we have to make a decision bewteen these two for managing our application logs. From what we've known (please correct me if I'm wrong).

> `systemd-journald` is a single-thread process which means it could potentially lead to some scaling issues from the long run.

So managing our application logs through TCP over rsyslog might sound the right way to follow, right? Or is there a better way besides these two?

Answer (score 0):

You actually usually run both. Rsyslog then reads messages from the journal. I guess (but am not sure) that the journal cannot receive messages from other log sources (like routers etc), so you need rsyslog in any case if need their logs.

Journal integration is done via [imjournal](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imjournal.html).